# Userinput scanner unknow source

Tags: java

i run the code it gives an these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Main.start(Main.java:15)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

this code is ment to take the input out of the main then put the data in the save and let the text you add to the file safe the words and keeps updating but i keep getting errors whit wrong user input if some1 can help me fix the error i would apprecieet it here the code there in the directionary and the files are connect (no package needed)

Main   java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

    Save option = new Save();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.start();
    }

    public void start(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1. Add random words to file");
        int result = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        if (result == 1 ) {
            try{
                String safeWordsString = "";
                System.out.println("Type some words");
                safeWordsString = scanner.nextLine();
                option.safeWords(safeWordsString);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Save  java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Save
{
    public void safeWords(String saveTekst)
    {
        try{

            //USER INPUT BINNEHALEN
            // Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            // System.out.println("Welke regel wil je toevoegen");
            // String regel = userInput.nextline();

            // ORIGINELE DATA VERZAMELEN
            File original = new File("test.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(original);
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
            while (scanner.hasNext()){
                temp.append(scanner.nextLine() + "\n");
            }

            // NIUEWE DATA APPENDEN
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(original);
            pw.println(temp);
            pw.println(new Date() + " " + saveTekst);
            pw.close();
            System.out.println("End");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will make a program that add to file the text of the user would to add to it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should accept your input as `String`

> 

```
public void start(){
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("1. Add random words to file");
  String result = scanner.nextLine();
  if("1".equals(result)){
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the program itself, you are trying to get the integer from Scanner..
if the integer is 1, then you are proceeding further to add random words, it is just like choosing an option from list of options..

Here you have only 1 option, so please choose it first(type 1 and enter), then proceed further to add your random words..

Comment: yes but i fixed that by adding a second scanner.nextLine under it to reset the scanner to string and i need to learn oop programming so i need to make more option soon

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what you are trying to say.. In the program, you are reading an integer first by calling nextInt().. so the program is expecting integer value first as input.. because of that when you enter string instead of integer.. you are getting exception..